# Why is this For loop not not the same as this While loop in Bash?

Tags: bash, variables, loops

Okay, so I'm trying to parse a file that outputs in columns what I need in rows, and I can't get this `while` loop to work, and I'm really stumped.

Interestingly, doing almost the exact same thing with a `for` loop *does* work. Can someone please explain what's going on here?

This...

```
e=""
for f in 1 2 3
do 
    echo $f 
    e="$e.$f"
done
echo $e
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
.1.2.3
```

But this...

```
e=""
echo "1
2
3" | while read f
do 
    echo $f 
    e="$e.$f"
done
echo $e
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
```

Clearly both loops have 1, 2, or 3 in `$f` when they get to `e="$e.$f"`, so what the heck is going on that the second one doesn't work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't tell you how many times I've had to pull this bug out of someone's code.

Basically the pipe generates a forked process.  e is set in the forked process, but when that terminates (at the end of the wile loop) the parent process does not know that e has changed.  In short, never set a variable in a command involving a pipe. It will not be set when the pipe finishes.  Shorter... Don't use pipes if they can be avoided.

```
e=''
while read f
do
  echo $f
  e="$e.$f"
done << EOF
1
2
3
EOF
echo $e
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! My second question was going to be "how do I fix it?"

Answer (score 3):

pipe will be executed in a sub-shell.  so the variable e was not changed after the piped command execution.

Comment: yes, even if you export in while loop, the var cannot be "pushed" to father shell either.

Answer (score 3):

As the `while read... done` is part of a pipeline, it gets its own forked process image just like other binaries (that's called a **subshell**). (The confusing part is that it's written in shell, but nevertheless it isn't executed as part of the current shell process.) That's why the variables won't get updates.

as a workaround, you can alway do something like this (uses bashisms):

```
while read line
do
    blablabla
done < <(echo "1 2 3")
```

Here, you avoid setting up a pipeline, and so the `while...done` shell code is executed as part of your current script.

Comment: +1 for showing me a new notation. I've never seen `<()` before.

Comment: That's called **process substitution** and is not very portable (but can be simulated by creating a temporary file)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is a difference in the scope of the variables. When you pipe your echo statement into the while statement, the global e is not in its scope, so it prints the f and sets a new variable e. When the while loop exits, the global e has not changed. Hence your statement `echo $e` prints nothing.

Comment: Pipes have their own local scope? 0_o

Comment: It's sort of you like the echo is a forked process and returns nothing. It is a child process and gets a new scope. If you could pass the e as a reference to the command, it would update the globally accessible e.